# My fahrenheit-celcius program ignores my if-else statement and changes value to 0 everytime I run the program

Tags: c++, if-statement

My if-else statement doesn't seem to work, anyone have any ideas?

So I created this simple Fahrenheit-Celcius conversion console app using C++. The program uses a simple if-else statement to determine which conversion they want, Fahrenheit-Celcius or Celcius-Fahrenheit.

The code currently doesn't work, however, it instantly converts Celcius-Fahrenheit and completely ignores the `std::cin` I put to grab user input. Instead, they put in the value of 0 everytime I run the program.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    unsigned short int fahrenheit{}, celsius{};
    char unit;

    cout << "Choose what unit you want to start with" << endl;
    cin >> unit;
    if (unit == 'c') {
        cout << "Enter the temperature in Celsius : " << endl;
        cin >> celsius;
        fahrenheit = (celsius * 9.0) / 5.0 + 32;
        cout << "The temperature in Fahrenheit : " << fahrenheit << endl;

    } else {
        cout << "Enter the temperature in Fahrenheit : " << endl;
        cin >> fahrenheit;
        fahrenheit = (celsius * 9.0) / 5.0 + 32;
        cout << "The temperature in Celcius : " << celsius << endl;
    }

    std::cin.clear(); // reset any error flags
    std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n'); // ignore any characters in the input buffer until we find an enter character
    std::cin.get(); // get one more char from the user

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: 1. Your `if` works - [I checked online](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/829279b4569dbd2b). 2. Your `else` branch is wrong. You input `fahrenheit` and then override its value with the calc. from `celsius` (which is uninitialized in this case).

Comment: @JeJo _The type of `fahrenheit`/ `celsius` must be floating-point type_ I don't agree. The calculations are done with double (promotion), and the "rounding" of results might be intended. Though, your concerns about (un-)signedness, I would support. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

in the if condition, use `unit=='C' || unit=='c'`. May be you entered uppercase. and remove `unsign` for negative value, and convert `int to double` for floating answer. in the else condition `fahrenheit = (celsius * 9.0) / 5.0 + 32;` is wrong, it will be `celsius = ( fahrenheit - 32) * 5.0 / 9.0`..

Answer (score 1):

In else block, you have **not** set value for **celsius**.
I guess you want to do something like that:

```
celsius = (fahrenheit - 32) * 5 / 9.0;
```

But, your code is

```
fahrenheit = (celsius * 9.0) / 5.0 + 32;
```